# Compiler error when passing 2D array to a function without specifiying 2nd dimension

Tags: c++, arrays, compiler-errors, argument-passing, multidimensional-array

Why does this work:

```
void SomeFunction(int SomeArray[][30]);
```

but this doesn't?

```
void SomeFunction(int SomeArray[30][]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, when passing an array as an argument the first `[]` is optional, however the 2nd onwards parameters are mandatory. That is the convention of the language grammar.

Moreover, you are not actually passing the array, but a pointer to the array of elements `[30]`. For better explanation, look at following:

```
T a1[10], a2[10][20];
T *p1;    // pointer to an 'int'
T (*p2)[20];  // pointer to an 'int[20]'

p1 = a1;  // a1 decays to int[], so can be pointed by p1
p2 = a2;  // a2 decays to int[][20], so can be pointed by p2
```

Also remember that, `int[]` is another form of `int*` and `int[][20]` is another form of `int (*)[20]`

Comment: "int[] is another form of int* and int[][20] is another form of int (*)[20]" -- Only in parameter lists.  In normal declarations, int[] is an array of however many ints are in its initialization list, likewise with int[][20].

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, you are correct. My answer was in the context of the argument passing only.

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, because the compiler cannot compute a constant size for the elements of the formal in the second declaration. Each element there has type `int[]` which has no known size at compile time.

Formally, because the standard C++ specification disallow that syntax!

You might want to use `std::array` or `std::vector` templates of C++11.